# how to actually use the data requested using discord oauth2

Tags: javascript, express, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I am not exactly sure how to go about using/accessing the data requested from a discord oauth2 authentication. I have requested to access the guilds the user is in and the username and avatar of the user. I get a successful authentication, but my question is how do i use and access that data? This is my code currently:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(50451, () => {
  console.info('Running on port 50451');
});

app.use('/api/discord', require('./api/discord'));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  switch (err.message) {
    case 'NoCodeProvided':
      return res.status(400).send({
        status: 'ERROR',
        error: err.message,
      });
    default:
      return res.status(500).send({
        status: 'ERROR',
        error: err.message,
      });
  }
});
```

discord.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const btoa = require('btoa');
const { catchAsync } = require('../utils');

const router = express.Router();
const scopes = ['identify', 'guilds'];

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirect =       
encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:50451/api/discord/callback');

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${redirect}&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds`);
});

router.get('/callback', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.code) throw new Error('NoCodeProvided');
  const code = req.query.code;
  const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
  const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirect}`,
    {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
  },
});
  const json = await response.json();
  res.redirect(`/success/?token=${json.access_token}`);
}));

module.exports = router;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same as the way you use the `req.query.code` to get the `access_token`.

```
const fetchDiscordUserInfo = await fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${json.access_token}`,
  }
});
const userInfo = await fetchDiscordUserInfo.json();

yourUserId = `${userInfo.id}`;
yourUserName = `${userInfo.username}`;

// or simply...
console.log(userInfo);
```